# I have trouble with updating existing aws cloud front CNAMEs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to add CNAMEs for the existing Distribution in aws cloud front programmatically.

I have tried the following code, but it did not give any result. If someone knows how to do it programmatically. Please kind enough to mention it. Thank you

```
      AmazonCloudFront cloudFront = AmazonCloudFrontAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withRegion(Regions.AP_EAST_1)
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                                new BasicAWSCredentials(route53Manager.getAccessKey(), route53Manager.getSecretKey())))
                        .build();

                GetDistributionConfigResult result = cloudFront.getDistributionConfig(
                        new GetDistributionConfigRequest("E1EJBNNYJZ6G34"));

                Aliases aliases = new Aliases()
                        .withItems(subDomain)
                        .withQuantity(1);
                DistributionConfig config = result.getDistributionConfig()
                        .withEnabled(true)
                        .withAliases(aliases);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the update distribution code and a few extra things. See the below code:

```
AmazonCloudFront cloudFront = AmazonCloudFrontAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
    .withRegion(Regions.AP_EAST_1)
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
        new BasicAWSCredentials(route53Manager.getAccessKey(), route53Manager.getSecretKey())))
    .build();

//create the request
GetDistributionConfigRequest distributionConfigRequest = new GetDistributionConfigRequest("E1EJBNNYJZ6G34");

//submit the request and get the resulting config
GetDistributionConfigResult distributionConfigResult = cloudFront.getDistributionConfig(distributionConfigRequest);

Aliases aliases = new Aliases()
    .withItems(subDomain)
    .withQuantity(1);

DistributionConfig config = distributionConfigResult.getDistributionConfig()
    .withEnabled(true)
    .withAliases(aliases);

//create the update request
UpdateDistributionRequest updateDistributionRequest = new UpdateDistributionRequest(config, distributionConfigRequest.getId(), distributionConfigResult.getETag());

//submit the request to update the config
UpdateDistributionResult updateDistributionResult = cloudfront.updateDistribution(updateDistributionRequest);

//print output of result to console
System.out.println(updateDistributionResult);
```